# How to make a div inside a div scroll (max bottom of the page)

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm struggling with this problem for over an hour now and I just can't get it right.

[Fiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKLT/)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">This is the header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="top-container">This is the top content container</div>
        <div class="bottom-container">
            <div class="scroll-container">
                This is the container that scrolls
                 ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page is separated into 2 sections. A header and a content div. The content is separatend again into 2 sections. The top and bottom container. I want to make the bottom container scrollable when the content is too large to show on the screen.

This means that the bottom container scrolls under the top container. The header container and top container in the content container should not move. The scrollbar should only be in the bottom-container and not on the whole page.

How can I get this done?

---

[EDIT]

To make it more clear. The height of the content/bottom container div is unknown, in **%** and **px**.

I'm already a bit further: [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKLT/3/)

Comment: set a fixed height http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/5BKLT/1/

Comment: @AdamAzad, That doesn't set it to the bottom of the page. it's unknown how much space is available on different screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle answer](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKLT/7/)

I made the bottom container fill the remaining space with

```
position:relative;
display:table-row;
height: 100%;
```

Then the boundaries of the scroll container are set with

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px; /* Set the top because the top container is within the boundaries */
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: auto; /* only y-scroll when neccesary */
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I'm still not really happy with this fix as i need to set the top to the height of the top container. If someone has suggestions to fix this, please let me know!

---

[EDIT]

[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKLT/9/)

Fixed my issue with a wrapper around the scroll-container. The bottom-container now sets the boundaries for all underlying elements, and the scroll-container fills the space to scroll.

```
.bottom-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.scroll-container-wrap {
    position:relative;
    display:table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bottom-container" style="height:50%; overflow:auto;">
//use overflow= auto to make it scroll
```

I think this will help you.

Just use overflow in every div you want to have a scroll tab

Comment: But you set the height to 50%. Does this work when no height is known and the max height is the height of the screen?

Comment: to set the maxheight of the screen simply set it to 100%..sorry to say that you need to set the height of the div to use the overflow..but percent is the good way to set height if your using overflow

Comment: Sorry but that is not the solution I requested. See the updated fiddle. I'm getting close now

Answer (score 0):

Apply `50%` for the top and bottom container.

```
.top-container {
position: relative;
background-color: blue;
height:50%;
}
.bottom-container {
background-color: grey;
position:relative;
overflow: auto; 
height:50%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5BKLT/2/)